# Embedded Fonts Not Working on Wordpress Stylesheet

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts, wordpress-theming

I've been trying to add some embedded fonts to the styles.css file of a theme and for some reason I can't seem to get the fonts to work. The code I have currently is:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'borisblackboxxregular';
    src: url('http://blog.abstract-thinking.co.uk/fonts/borisblackboxxregular/borisblackbloxx-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://blog.abstract-thinking.co.uk/fonts/borisblackboxxregular/borisblackbloxx-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('http://blog.abstract-thinking.co.uk/fonts/borisblackboxxregular/borisblackbloxx-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('http://blog.abstract-thinking.co.uk/fonts/borisblackboxxregular/borisblackbloxx-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('http://blog.abstract-thinking.co.uk/fonts/borisblackboxxregular/borisblackbloxx-webfont.svg') format('svg');
}
```

However I've also tried (just one line as an example):

```
src: url('/fonts/borisblackboxxregular/borisblackbloxx-webfont.eot');
src: url('.../fonts/borisblackboxxregular/borisblackbloxx-webfont.eot');
src: url('borisblackbloxx-webfont.eot');
```

The physical location for the fonts is in several places, the root folder of the install, in a fonts/borisblackboxxregular folder structure and in the root of the currently applied theme. Does anybody know what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks to anyone who can answer this.

Comment: I might be asking a silly question, but have you actually called the font on an element in your CSS - e.g. `body { font-family: 'borisblackboxxregular'; }`? Also, have you checked the developer console in your browser to see if you are getting any 404's for the fonts?

Comment: All checked and double-checked - still no luck

Comment: On what element are you using the font? Post that CSS as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some font settings option in the theme, that produce:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7 {
    font-family: "header-font"!important;
}
```

This code is coming from your theme's settings page. There is two options for you to fix it.

1. You can go to the theme's php code and remove the font style.
2. You can override by writing following css in footer.php before closing `<body>` tag.

   h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, a {
       font-family: 'borisblackboxxregular' !important;
   }